# Debug an active x dll in vb6

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

i am trying to debug an application in vb6 which has output type ActiveX Exe , and have reference of active dll , i have tried changing to binary compability for both of projects. but i am not able to step into that activex dll project code. can you help me with step into other project dll and debug code ? i have even tried creating project group but even i am setting up Exe project as start up , i think it is trying to run dll project first and giving an error.

Comment: When you changed the DLL project to bincomp, did you then recompile it? And then did you make sure the EXE project was referencing the new DLL? It may have retained a reference to the old DLL before bincomp was enabled.

Comment: You will need to create a Standard EXE test project to debug the ActiveX EXE.  Here is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2886104/5162073) with background information and links showing how to get this done.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs yes i have updated as bincomp , and also recompiled it, and also made sure exe project referencing the new dll. but still no success.

Comment: @BrianMStafford so you meant to say i can't step into activex dll which is referenced in ActiveX EXE ?

Comment: From the test exe you should be able to step into the activex exe and then into the dll.  The link shows how to set this up.

Comment: If you mean that the EXE references the DLL, you can load them both in the same project group in the VB6 IDE and directly debug them at the same time. If its the other way around (the DLL calls into the EXE) then Brian's link explains that (somewhat more complicated) scenario

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs yes i tried creating project group and trying set up as StartUp for my Exe project but idk some how it try to run DLL project and get error message.

Comment: If you can explain that error in more detail it might help.

Comment: You can debug the ActiveX module with Visual Studio 2015.