# How to debug ActiveX dll in VB6?

Tags: c#, vb6

I have two project in VB6 one is ActiveX DLL
one is ActiveX EXE, as i am not able to step into ActiveX DLL project which added as reference in ActiveX EXE, can any one let me know why ?

I have tried creating Project Group but still facing problem since it tries to run DLL Project even though i set EXE Project as Start UP.

Second i want to migrate ActiveX DLL in c# and then by adding COM c# dll reference in VB6 ActiveX EXE Project , i want to test and debug ,

Please help with this. Thanks in advance if you can provide steps it would be great.

Comment: Here's [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59851425/5162073) from 2 days ago.

Comment: To answer your first question, if you have a Project Group containing a **STANDARD** EXE and the ActiveX DLL with the exe having a reference to the dll, you should be able to debug the code in the dll.  To debug the ActiveX EXE, please refer to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, a very very long time ago, I did it. generate a ".tlb" using Tlbexp.exe.

"*Tlbexp.exe generates a type library with definitions of the types defined in the assembly. Applications, such as Visual Basic 6.0, can use the generated type library to link to the .NET types defined in the assembly.*"

[Tlbexp.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbexp-exe-type-library-exporter)